# Menu function of urls

Tags: routes

I know how to use Drupal's Menu and how to manage rights to access them function of profiles but I need to show secondary menu function of urls.
For example:
- A partner menu is only shown in page where url starts with /partners/
- This partener menu becomes beneficiary if url starts with /beneficiary.

Do you idea how can I manage it ? I cannot usse session :-(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use any of these modules. I hope any of these modules solve your issues :

1. [NodeSymlinks](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodesymlinks)

> This is useful when you want to have the same page reachable though
>   multiple menu items, each with its own URL, menu trail and breadcrumb
>   path.

2. [Menu Trail By Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_trail_by_path)

> Menu Trail By Path sets the active-trail on menu items according to
>   the current url.